# Nginx: Multiple PHP sites in sub-directories

Tags: php, nginx, virtualhost, statamic

I've been pulling my hair out for hours now.

My [statamic CMS] sites are running in subdirectories on a staging server.

- domain.com/site1/
- domain.com/site2/
- domain.com/site3/

I'm using and NGINX conf provided by Statamic:

https://gist.github.com/jackmcdade/3866603

Which I've modified like so:

https://gist.github.com/LkeMitchll/b6d8aea6c0845e3a341f

All is working but...

**...when I navigate to *domain.com/site1/_config/users/admin.yaml* I can download the file without restriction!(!!)**

The NGINX config line in question is:

`location ~ /.(yml|yaml|html) { deny all; }`

I've tried the following but no luck:

`location ~ /(site1|site2|site3)/.+\.(yml|yaml|html) { deny all; }`

To be honest I'm a complete n00b at NGINX, and it's proving much more difficult to use than Apache.

So my question is how do I modify the above statement to restrict access to the .yaml and .html files?

Thanks.

LM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. It requires a `$` to match end of string.

```
location ~* (?:\.(?:yml|yaml|html)|~)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Working! Sorry, forgot to clear the cache. Thanks!